# How to share file p2p with wifi direct

Tags: android

I'm developing an app demo using wifi direct to share file. I have read api about [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).
But this demo shares image from client side (socket) to server side (ServerSocket). Now i wanna share file p2p, from client side to server side and from server side to client side.
Please suggest me way to resolve this issue.
And I wanna share file (not only image) but i can not fix source code to resolve it. 
Please help me! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.alljoyn.org/
https://www.alljoyn.org/sites/default/files/alljoyn-alliance.pdf

You can try this. I think this is easy to use, and fit your requirement.

Comment: I can find solution to resolve my problem there. I just want to share files between android mobile using wifi direct.